# JBoss 7 RestEasy...services not being registered?

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

I am upgrading my app to JBoss 7.1.1 and will now be using RestEasy.  I am having issues getting RestEasy to work.  I get the error HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative.  I believe this means that it can't find the correct endpoint.  My suspicion is that there is some issue scanning and registering the services.  I could be wrong though.  Note: I am not using Maven

Here is the portion of my web.xml that is concerned with RestEasy:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is a sample resource I am using:

```
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {

@POST
@Produces("text/plain")
public String helloResource() {
    return "Hello!";
}
}
```

The url I have tried is: http://localhost:8080/[project-name]/rest/hello

I think that is all I am using for the call.  If additional info is required to answer my question, don't hesitate to ask.  Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. - How do the files need to be structured in the WAR?

**[Updated web.xml]**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>com.elderscan.test.RestEasyExample</param-value>
</context-param> 

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
     </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.elderscan.test.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So this allows me to successfully make a call to RestEasyExample, but I cannot make calls to another other rest services, which I obviously need to do.  Furthermore, this solution of adding all of my services to xml is not ideal, so another way would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up solving this.  The key was to include this to what I already had, where each singleton is a rest service:

```
public class MyApplication  extends Application {
private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

public MyApplication() {
    singletons.add(new RestEasyExample());
    singletons.add(new RestEasyExample2());
}

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return singletons;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right about your suspicion.. Try adding this to your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I am going to add some updates to my original post, as I have made some changes to web.xml, but I previously had the snippet you provided in there, and I would get a warning statement that the resteasy.scan was being ignored (I think it is defaulted in JBoss 7).  It then fails on deployment.    [Added later] - when I try this on my new web.xml, I deploy just fine, but I get a http status of 500, and it gives me the error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a public constructor for class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatche, which is what the deployment used to fail on.